# Python, finding the max difference in an arraylist

Tags: python

Hi I am on this problem where you have to find the difference in an array list
I know how to do that

```
def diff(list):
 return max(list)-min(list)
```

but I need to do it a for loop. Can anybody help me get started

Comment: What's an "array list"?  And why do you need to use a loop?

Comment: What do you mean by "do it a for loop"?

Comment: What's an arraylist? Do you mean a list? And is this homework?

Comment: I am sorry,an array of integers. I am still new to this. He ask it to use a loop. Im just confused on how to get it started

Comment: Why would you need to do it in a for loop when you have a readable and efficient solution already?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to get the maximum of a list using a `for` loop:

```
yourmax = None
for x in yourlist:
    if yourmax is None or x > yourmax:
        yourmax = x
```

This doesn't answer your entire question, but you should be able to see how to adapt this code to get the minimum value. For extra credit, see if you can get both the minimum and maximum in a single iteration of the list (i.e. just one `for` loop).

Also: don't use `list` as a variable name because it shadows the built-in of the same name.